# Successful Export (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard) but No Data on Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis

I am looking for help with exporting data to the SQL server database.

I export CSV to the SQL server DB and despite the transfer is successful, no data appears in the server database. I am unable to find the cause of the issue.

I am using the "Export and Import Wizard" via SSIS in Visual Studio. I do not want to create a new table but import data from CSV to the existing table.

- The table had the data previously but I cleared it with DELETE command [epic00](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQWw2.png)
- The CSV file is on the local machine (C drive)
- Data type: single-byte signed integer [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81uw3.png)
- Checked Enable Identity insert [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywf2K.png)
- Rows and columns seem to be OK [pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Rbg.png)

  [Operation appears to be successful...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym91U.png)

  [... but no data is found in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4MpQ.png)
- I can't use this wizard in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio due to the differences between 64-bit PC and 32-bit program
- I can't use the SQL Server developer because of the errors during the installation and I can't resolve it now
- I tried to use the bulk insert task in Visual Studio but I got errors

What I want? Export the data from csv file to existing table in SQL Server database. Do you have any idea what I should check?

I had some errors when I tried to export CSV to SQL server database before:

> Validating (Error)
>
> Messages
> Error 0xc0202049: Data Flow Task 1: Failure inserting into the read-only column "ParameterSet".
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0202045: Data Flow Task 1: Column metadata validation failed.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - inputParameters" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 1: One or more component failed validation.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error: 0xC002F304 at Bulk Insert Task, Bulk Insert Task: An error occurred with the following error message: "Cannot bulk load because the file " could not be opened. Operating system error code (null).".

But once I changed the type of the data (DataType) to **single-byte signed integer** and made sure that is ticked **Enable Identity insert** the errors did not appear again.

Comment: [pic4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym91U.png) doesn't show any rows being inserted, so I would expect none in the table. It looks like you saved a copy of the dtsx file, rather than executing it.

Comment: If you *had* imported data, it would look more like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEYjg.png).